# Magento Module issue

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Magento 2.2.6 Porto Theme and Land of Cooder Market Place

```
   1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Ves\Themesettings\Helper\Image does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Ves\Themesettings\Helper\Image does not exist
#0 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#1 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#2 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#3 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#4 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(122): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#5 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Lof_MarketPlace/templates/product/list.phtml(30): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->helper('Ves\\Themesettin...')
#6 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/427182.cl...')
#7 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor), '/home/427182.cl...', Array)
#8 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/427182.cl...')
#9 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/427182.cl...')
#10 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#11 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callParent('toHtml', Array)
#13 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#14 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php(897): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callPlugins('toHtml', Array, Array)
#15 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->toHtml()
#16 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('seller.products...')
#17 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('seller.products...')
#18 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('seller.products...')
#19 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('seller.products...', true)
#20 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('seller.products...', true)
#21 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View/Interceptor.php(388): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#22 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/app/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View.php(155): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor->getChildHtml('product_list')
#23 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View/Interceptor.php(37): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View->getProductListHtml()
#24 [internal function]: Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor->getProductListHtml()
#25 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(82): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/app/code/Lof/MarketPlace/view/frontend/templates/seller/view.phtml(2): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->__call('getProductListH...', Array)
#27 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/427182.cl...')
#28 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor), '/home/427182.cl...', Array)
#29 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View/Interceptor.php(154): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/427182.cl...')
#30 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor->fetchView('/home/427182.cl...')
#31 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/app/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View.php(200): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#32 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View/Interceptor.php(63): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View->_toHtml()
#33 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor->_toHtml()
#34 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Lof/MarketPlace/Block/Seller/View/Interceptor.php(479): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#35 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Lof\MarketPlace\Block\Seller\View\Interceptor->toHtml()
#36 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('seller.products')
#37 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('seller.products')
#38 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('seller.products')
#39 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('seller.products', false)
#40 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('seller.products', false)
#41 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#42 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#43 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#44 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#45 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false)
#46 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#47 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#48 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#49 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#50 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false)
#51 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#52 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#53 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#54 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#55 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false)
#56 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#57 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#58 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#59 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#60 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false)
#61 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#62 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#63 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#64 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#65 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#66 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#67 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#68 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#69 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#70 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#71 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#72 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#73 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#74 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#75 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#76 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#77 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#78 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#79 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/app/code/Magezon/Core/Plugin/View/Result/Layout.php(24): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#80 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magezon\Core\Plugin\View\Result\Layout->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#81 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
```

(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#82 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#83 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#84 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#85 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#86 /home/427182.cloudwaysapps.com/gravqhssbb/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#87 {main}

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have **Ves_All** module installed, if it is installed please check its enabled or not.

Comment: I use Porto Theme. I dont have Ves theme Modules. Can you share me this modules?